# Manage internet connection for a programm

Tags: networking, proxy

I'am using a Xp proffesional pc with 2 networkcards

one for public line and one for internal line behind proxy.

is there a way or a software programm where i can manage wich programm(outlook, WM) use wich internet connection or networkcard

use the option of `interface metric` is not where i was looking for

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a question best suited for the SuperUser site.

Since you are here now, and I cannot move it, you could use firewall software, like ZoneAlarm to do this.

First define both networks in ZoneAlarm

Next you can allow / disallow each program access to each network.

Hopefully this will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: i dislike zonealarm, but thanks for the tip

Comment: I have gotten used to it, it is free for personal use, powerful and very configurable, though it can be a real PITA at times. Other software firewalls should be able to do similar things for you, I am just not as familiar with the others as I am with ZoneAlarm.